What are maximum turns ratios of transformer? Do we really need a turns ratio meter with turns ratio range of 1-50,000?
I'm studying transformer turns ratio and suitable turns ratio measurers. I found that some turns ratio meters have range of 0.8 - 10,000 and even up to 0.8-50,000. My question is how the maximum turns ratios of transform are? Do we really need too high turns ratio meters. Thank you in advance.

why would such an instrument be manufactured and sold if there was no use for it?

Excess turns ratio can create a problem with capacitance, resonance, or other critical parameters.  But ignition coils use it.

@jsotola: Yes, i had the same question as yours, then now i need answers to verify the need for 1:50,000 turns ratio meter

@D.A.S. Thank you

There is no maximum to the turns ratio of a transformer. You could have a 1:1M transformer if you wanted. It would be a highly specialized component, but it could exist.
Practically, the largest turns ratios I'm aware of are found in flyback converters for generating high voltage from a battery (such as ignition coils in a car), and in current transformers for measuring very high currents. 1:50k is a ratio I wouldn't expect to see outside of a very large current transformer.
Whether you need a meter capable of measuring a 1:50k turns ratio is down to what you need to measure, and not something I can answer here. If all transformers you expect to work with have turns ratios less than 1:10k, then the lower-spec one will do just fine. If not, you're going to need the higher-spec one. If you need to measure transformers with ratios higher than 1:50k, then you need to find one that can measure higher than that.
It's always also possible to measure a turns ratio by simply applying a signal on one side and measuring the response on the other, too. This is, internally, what these turns-ratio meters do. The specialized meter may be convenient, but you can also perform the necessary measurements with an oscilloscope--or even just a multimeter--and a function generator.

Thank you for your answers. It's clear for me now
